# OnCreateOptionMenu is never called

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I'm not able to dispay `Menù` in my main Activity and all the other Activities.
This is my `main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_light_background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/articoli"
                android:onClick="visualizzaArticoli"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Articoli"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main.java file:

```
package com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.R;
import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.beans.Program;
import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.connection.MyDatabase;
import com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.utility.SyncDati;

public class Main extends Activity {
    public MyDatabase db;
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    public String url="";
    private static final Intent SCAN_INTENT = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.care_home, menu);
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }
    private void apriConnessioneDB(){
        db=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();  //apriamo il db
    }
    public void visualizzaArticoli(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.mcsolution.easymanagementandroid.articoli.viewArticoli.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }   
}
```

This is my menu care_home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
   <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Logout"/>
</menu>
```

If I try to start my application, I don't have any error but I can't to see `MenuBar`. I have try to set a debug point into `OnCreateOptionMenu` method but, the method is never called.
How can I fixed it ?

Comment: You must `return true;` from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for your menu to actually be used. Not sure about your breakpoint issue.

Comment: you return super method instance in onCreateOptionsMenu, just return true only.

Comment: I'm try to use all code that we have write but Menù not display. It is possible that I used Android 6.0 and there is another component ?

Comment: @bircastri did you solved it..?

Answer (score 2):

You need to **`return true;`** in **`onCreateOptionsMenu()`** as shown in the code below

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.care_home, menu);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.care_home, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your activity class extends `Activity`, not `AppCompatActivity`. The default theme for these activities does not include an Action Bar, which is where the menu would live. You will need to add a `<Toolbar>` to your activity's layout file, and then call `setActionBar()` from your `onCreate()` method.

For example, add this as the first child of your top-level `<LinearLayout>` tag:

```
<Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And add this just after you call `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setActionBar(toolbar);
```

Now you will have an Action Bar in your activity, and so your menu will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should return true instead of super like this:

```
 @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    if (menu != null) {

    }
    return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use both methods on your activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);        
    }
```